# Omission of "the" in "elected him president" and "made captain"

Tags: articles, zero-article

Why is there no *the* before *president* and *captain*?

> They elected him president.
>
> She was made captain of the team.

Comment: I've always taken the first example to have an elided "as". "They elected him as president."

Comment: Related: [Should there be an article before “mayor” in “the role of mayor”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54837/should-there-be-an-article-before-mayor-in-the-role-of-mayor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people omit the definite article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/why-do-people-omit-the-definite-article)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ (LSGSWE) explains it thus:

> When a predicative noun phrase names a unique role or job, either a
>   zero article or *the* is used.

*The* is not normally found after words like *elected* (and *re-elected*) which show that someone has been appointed to an office. The LSGSWE’s own example is ‘Lukman was re-elected OPEC President in June.’ In other cases, however, it’s optional. The LSGSWE’s second example is: ‘Simon Burns is the chairman of the appeal board.’ That could equally well appear as ‘Simon Burns is chairman . . .’

Comment: One also commonly uses the verb "To make" intransitively, meaning "to attain the rank of," e.g. "I made captain," "I finally made partner."

Comment: For once, I've voted for closure on the grounds of there being a later, better duplicate. Longman's explanation is simplistic, and fails to distinguish the zero article from the null article (we had chicken for tea / they elected him President). Note that 'a' is a possible insertion without a vast semantic switch in the former, but 'the' in the latter. There is a gradience of definiteness / gravitas: zero ... indefinite ... definite ... null.