# If I were elected president

Tags: grammar, articles

Presidential candidates say "If I were elected president" but why don't they add an article in the sentence? Shouldn't it be "If I were elected a president"? After all, we do add articles in sentences like "When I become a mother" and "While I was a captain." Could someone explain?

Comment: I think your question is answered here: [Omission of "the" in "elected him president" and "made captain"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56365/omission-of-the-in-elected-him-president-and-made-captain)

Comment: You wouldn't use the indefinite article - '**a**' - that's for sure, because the candidates are talking about *the specific president* not any old presidential job.