# Why there is no article before "heire"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, early-modern-english, shakespeare

The following passage is from [All's Well That Ends Well](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2246):

*Shee is young, wise, faire,
In these, to Nature shee's immediate heire:
And these breed honour:*

According to the research I did [on Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heir) *heir* is countable. If so, why there is no article before *heire*? Likewise, 
*The French finance minister is heir to a tradition of central control that goes back to Louis XIV.*

Comment: This is clearly Elizabethan English. The rules were different back then. Further, we usually don't use an article in the expression *is heir to*, when it's used metaphorically.

Comment: Related: [Omission of “the” in “elected him president” and “made captain”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56365)

Comment: @sumelic Yes, the first is poetry, auld poetry at that (and hence probably better not analysed according to the usual rules); the second is the [null article, as discussed by Lawrence ... after Peter Master](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/why-do-people-omit-the-definite-article/427204#427204) (contrasted with the _zero article_).